# Display custom alert box like facebook when you navigate to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]
I want to show custom alert box instead of browser default alert box when user tries to navigate from the existing page. Using this code:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "are you sure?";
 }
```

I can use this code to alert user if he has any unsaved data and want to leave page. But I want to make custom alert box with my own design like facebook does. How it is possible? Something like:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    myownalertbox.show();  //here I want to bind leave page or stay on page button with my own button.
 }
```

And I want to bind stay on this page and leave this page button to my button.

Comment: `$('a').on('click', function() { alert('You're leaving ?') })`

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to display my own custom alert box.

Comment: Please remove "like facebook" from your title, as it hints the answerer of some Facebook functionality. "custom alert box" would be quite clear.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough, but the only way to consistently do this is to capture clicks on elements with outbound hrefs etc. and then popup your own modal before following the links etc. Unfortunately the comment field was too small for me to include a working modal, so I just used `alert` for illustrative purposes, I thought it was rather obvious that `alert` could be replaced by anything in that snippet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not with implementing custom alert boxes (as some of the other answers pointing it out), that's not a hard thing to do, there are plenty of solutions, framework, plugin, etc. The problem is JavaScript execution timing.

Using the `onbeforeunload` handler it's impossible to achieve your goal, because it needs to run "synchronously": you cannot display the alert, return something and then later with some callback get back and return the actual value. When you return from the function, the result will be used by the browser, and you will end up having your custom alert box shown, but the user action will be "lost", because the handler has already been finished.

To go further, I've never been able to find any solution which would provide a custom alert box, which behaves synchronously in this sense. By synchronous behavior I mean that code execution would be blocked until a user clicks on alert buttons. Every custom alert/confirm/prompt solution I've seen was using callbacks. And last but not least JavaScript doesn't even provide a way for kind of a "blocking waiting".

**UPDATE**

What you *can* do (and Facebook does it too) is to handle navigation links, buttons, clicks, etc. which you know that will leave the page, and there you can show a custom confirmation box.

**Note**: Actually I've tried Facebook, and for me (Windows 10, Chrome latest) it prompts the default confirmation box when I tried to close the browser tab, not any custom one. But when I clicked on a link, it indeed showed a custom confirmation box. So to summarize, Facebook, when possible, uses the custom one, and when not possible (only with `onbeforeunload`, like browser close, tab close, page reload, URL navigation, etc.) it uses the default handling mechanism.

**Note 2**: For 2016 it seems like all major browsers chose to not let developers customize the message which is shown on `onbeforeunload`, so your `string` return value from the handler will not be taken as the message. There are several articles about this. The main reason is safety, as lots of sites used it for tricking naive users and asking them do do some actions, or prompting them malicious content, etc. Now all major browsers display a default message about possibly having unsaved changes.

Comment: Could you confirm if FB is using backend to determine which navigational link triggered the custom alert box? When user clicks "Leave this Page", facebook takes used to the result of the action he clicked in the first place which invoked the custom alert box, is it possible with only javascript? I tried doing it with preventDefault but then it kills the default behaviour and it never gets executed. I checked the network logs, I think FB is using server-side to tackle with it, could anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

The orginal answer is suitable for IE6-8 and FX1-3.5 , but is rather out of date now and won't work in most current browsers - I've left it below for reference.

The `window.onbeforeunload` is not treated consistently by all browsers. It should be a function reference and not a string (as the original answer stated) but that will work in older browsers because the check for most of them appears to be whether anything is assigned to `onbeforeunload` (including a function that returns `null`).

You set `window.onbeforeunload` to a function reference, but in older browsers you have to set the `returnValue` of the event instead of just returning a string:

```
var confirmOnPageExit = function (e) 
{
    // If we haven't been passed the event get the window.event
    e = e || window.event;

    var message = 'Any text will block the navigation and display a prompt';

    // For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) 
    {
        e.returnValue = message;
    }

    // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
    return message;
};
```

You can't have that `confirmOnPageExit` do the check and return null if you want the user to continue without the message. You still need to remove the event to reliably turn it on and off:

```
// Turn it on - assign the function that returns the string
window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit;

// Turn it off - remove the function entirely
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

To turn it on:

```
window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
```

To turn it off:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Bear in mind that this isn't a normal event - you can't bind to it in the standard way.

To check for values? That depends on your validation framework.

In jQuery this could be something like (very basic example):

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != "" )
        window.onbeforeunload = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
});
```

Comment: But how to display custom alert box with divs like facebook does.

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to alert like those in facebook with custom alertbox in `window.onbeforeunload`, not the browser default alertbox and handle 'stay on page' and 'leave this page' with custom button.

Answer (score -1):

I would use some normal HTML layout, and play with CSS's `display:none;`/`display:block;`

For instance (you do your styling):

CSS:

```
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var myownalertbox = {

  show: function(message) {
    var popup = document.createElement("DIV");
    popup.className = "popup";
    document.body.appendChild(popup);
    popup.style.display = "block";
    popup.innerHTML = message;
    var ybutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    ybutton.innerHTML = "YES";
    var nbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    nbutton.innerHTML = "NO";
    ybutton.onclick = function () {
     // do with "YES"
     window.location = "/main.html"; // <-- go back to the main page
     popup.style.display = "none";
    }
    nbutton.onclick = function () {
     // do with "NO"
     window.location = "#"; // <-- stay at this page
     popup.style.display = "none";
    }
    popup.appendChild(ybutton);
    popup.appendChild(nbutton);
  }
}

myownalertbox.show("ARE YOU SURE?");
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcxzg9tw/2/).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this website.
http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/
It is not a custom alert box but it provides alert box that are actually quite beautiful.

Answer (score -1):

I am attaching you a link from where I used code to customize my dialog/alert boxes. Hope this might help you.

http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html